# Can we have collections in Solidity and Ethereum?

Tags: solidity, blockchain

Technologies i used are Ethereum and Solidity.

I am trying to store multiple row of data into the Blockchain-Ethereum with an unique ID one by one. When i try to pull the inserted rows of data from Blockchain with that particular unique ID, its returning me only the latest row which was inserted. How i can get the entire rows from Blockchain? The smart contract was build in solidity language.

Comment: Can you edit the question and put some part of your code ?

Comment: you want to get all the rows by using one ID?

Answer (score 2):

See arrays and mappings in the solidity docs: http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/types.html

For storage, you can use a compile-time fixed size array with fixed size `k` and element type `T`, written as `T[k]`.

Then you can "index" the data stored in the array with mappings:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;

contract MappingExample {
    mapping(address => uint) public balances;

    function update(uint newBalance) {
        balances[msg.sender] = newBalance;
    }
}

contract MappingUser {
    function f() returns (uint) {
        return MappingExample(<address>).balances(this);
    }
}
```

The code for iterating over data is more complex, but it is possible.
Here's a contract on github that illustrates this: https://github.com/ethereum/dapp-bin/blob/master/library/iterable_mapping.sol

And here's the full contract for reference:

```
/// @dev Models a uint -> uint mapping where it is possible to iterate over all keys.
library IterableMapping
{
  struct itmap
  {
    mapping(uint => IndexValue) data;
    KeyFlag[] keys;
    uint size;
  }
  struct IndexValue { uint keyIndex; uint value; }
  struct KeyFlag { uint key; bool deleted; }
  function insert(itmap storage self, uint key, uint value) returns (bool replaced)
  {
    uint keyIndex = self.data[key].keyIndex;
    self.data[key].value = value;
    if (keyIndex > 0)
      return true;
    else
    {
      keyIndex = self.keys.length++;
      self.data[key].keyIndex = keyIndex + 1;
      self.keys[keyIndex].key = key;
      self.size++;
      return false;
    }
  }
  function remove(itmap storage self, uint key) returns (bool success)
  {
    uint keyIndex = self.data[key].keyIndex;
    if (keyIndex == 0)
      return false;
    delete self.data[key];
    self.keys[keyIndex - 1].deleted = true;
    self.size --;
  }
  function contains(itmap storage self, uint key) returns (bool)
  {
    return self.data[key].keyIndex > 0;
  }
  function iterate_start(itmap storage self) returns (uint keyIndex)
  {
    return iterate_next(self, uint(-1));
  }
  function iterate_valid(itmap storage self, uint keyIndex) returns (bool)
  {
    return keyIndex < self.keys.length;
  }
  function iterate_next(itmap storage self, uint keyIndex) returns (uint r_keyIndex)
  {
    keyIndex++;
    while (keyIndex < self.keys.length && self.keys[keyIndex].deleted)
      keyIndex++;
    return keyIndex;
  }
  function iterate_get(itmap storage self, uint keyIndex) returns (uint key, uint value)
  {
    key = self.keys[keyIndex].key;
    value = self.data[key].value;
  }
}

// How to use it:
contract User
{
  // Just a struct holding our data.
  IterableMapping.itmap data;
  // Insert something
  function insert(uint k, uint v) returns (uint size)
  {
    // Actually calls itmap_impl.insert, auto-supplying the first parameter for us.
    IterableMapping.insert(data, k, v);
    // We can still access members of the struct - but we should take care not to mess with them.
    return data.size;
  }
  // Computes the sum of all stored data.
  function sum() returns (uint s)
  {
    for (var i = IterableMapping.iterate_start(data); IterableMapping.iterate_valid(data, i); i = IterableMapping.iterate_next(data, i))
    {
        var (key, value) = IterableMapping.iterate_get(data, i);
        s += value;
    }
  }
}
```

So if you want all data with a given UUID, you can use the UUID as the key and use the iterable mapping to get the data.